# Why can nobody join my server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hosting

I'm trying to get a minecraft server that costs $700 so today I decided that I would make a smaller, desktop run, server to get a bit of money for it. I go through the normal steps to start one up, Port forwarding and stuff like that. But when I start it up, the IP does not work. I left the IP empty so it would use my local IP, and i can connect to it by typing 'localhost' into the server list.

PS. My pc is connected to a wireless extender not the original router. I don't think that's the problem thow because I can access the 198.168.1.1 router configuration page from my pc.

Comment: What is the IP address that has been assigned to your router? You might be behind a carrier grade NAT.

Comment: could you rephrase that please

Comment: Your router, being a router, owns more than one IP address. The internal-facing IP address is 192.168.1.1. What is the external-facing one? You can _only_ get this answer by looking at the router status page.

Comment: K give me a second

Comment: how do i find it. im at the page but i dont see anything marked router status

Comment: Is it your router?  You may not have access to make modifications.

Answer (score 2):

`192.168.1.1` is a *private* IP address, which can only be accessed from the local area network that the local address is associated with. What you need to do is figure out the server's *public* IP address.

Since you're running the server on a standard desktop computer, it should be fairly easy to do this. Pull up a web browser and go to [whatismyip.com](https://www.whatismyip.com/). It'll display your device's public address right there on the page, no strings attached.

Comment: No. I mean i can access the router website. Im using my public ip and its not working

Comment: Elaborate? Because what I'm getting from the question is that you're trying to connect to the MC server using the public IP. Also, if possible, you might want to try connecting the PC directly to your router.

Comment: My public ip does not work. That's what i'm saying. What i ment by *" I don't think that's the problem thow because I can access the 198.168.1.1"* is that i could access my router's website from my computer. If you still dont know what i mean by this; type 198.168.1.1 into your search bar.

Comment: And my pc is out of range from my router

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean by the router's website. && Huh, never had this happen before.

Comment: @Can If you're trying to access your local machine by using the router's IP address it presents to the wider Internet, it is probably blocking you because routers typically disallow local loop-back in their networks. If you want to determine if the service is available externally, you need to try accessing it from an external source.